# How do I show and update something in JOptionPane while opened?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane, jslider

I'm trying to figure out how to show and update something in a JOptionPane while the Pane is still open.

To clarify myself: I'm trying to make a Window where the user is asked for their name and a color (using three sliders for the rgb code) like so:

http://puu.sh/c9Gtn/66b2733b84.png
(I can't post images since I don't have 10 reputation yet)

Now what I'm trying to do is show the actual color you're making whilst the user is sliding the bars.
I want a color to be shown below the sliding bars whilst he is chosing.

Comment: In which case, I would most definitely not use a JOptionPane, being that it is meant to be for quick, easy, and PREFORMATTED tools that most developers can pick up and use, it will not be very flexible. While it is technically possible, I would definitely recommend just doing it in a JFrame. Can you post the code behind this? I'll be able to help you out more that way

Comment: After alot of research, I managed to get what I want using JPane and adding a changeListener to the JSliders that repaints a component (containing the rectangle with the right color).
I'm still very new when it comes to swing, so I guess I should've done more research before asking questions.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I would recommend posting your answer anyways, a lot of ppl tend to have the same problem you do, posting your code might make things easier for them

Comment: In other words, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).